# How to Change RadioButton State from code behind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have RadioButton declared in  page as below :

```
<asp:RadioButton  ID="RadioSalesManager" runat="server" GroupName="RadioSales"  />

 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioSalesUser" runat="server"  GroupName="RadioSales"/>
```

In Code behind Based on the value of dropdown I want to change the state of RadioButton

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        strRole = ((RadioButtonList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")).SelectedValue;

        if (strRole.Contains("Administrator"))
        {
            ((DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("DrpGrpList")).SelectedValue = strRole.Trim();
            ((DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("DrpGrpList")).Enabled = false;
            ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("trAccess")).Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
               ((DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("DrpGrpList")).Enabled = true;
                    ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("trAccess")).Visible = true;
                    strGroupName = ((DropDownList)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("DrpGrpList")).SelectedValue;

                    if (strGroupName.Contains("Sales") && (strRole.Contains("Manager")))
                        ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RadioSalesManager")).Checked = true;
                    else
                        if (strGroupName.Contains("Sales") && (strRole.Contains("User")))
                            ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton)CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RadioSalesUser")).Checked = true;

        }
    }
```

The Radio Button State doesn't change with the above code behind code . Please help me in fixing the issue .

Thanks 
APPU

Comment: Are you hitting a breakpoint inside the method when the list is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a UpdatePanel in your aspx-Page?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

This is needed to update data in the frontend, which has been changed in code behind